# What does allowedfields mean in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

For example I have a table with columns:

1. username
2. email
3. password
4. **picture**

If I specify the allowedfields like this in **user model**:

```
protected $allowedFields = [
    'username', 'email', 'password',
];
```

In this case if I would like to edit the picture column with fill() method OR inserting new row into user table with picture value, then I would get an error, because user model is not allowed to update or inserting new value into picture column, right?

Source:
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/entities.html

Comment: see the doc `$allowedFields

This array should be updated with the field names that can be set during save, insert, or update methods. Any field names other than these will be discarded. This helps to protect against just taking input from a form and throwing it all at the model, resulting in potential mass assignment vulnerabilities.`

Comment: It basically means, whatever data come from post array it will only take `'username', 'email', 'password',` fields when saving.